# My internet connection requires a web based login after 90 minutes. What would be the best way to make sure I'm always online?

Tags: python, http, networking

I'm thinking of constantly pinging a website and use python http to send a POST request to the login server if the network is down. Any suggestions?

Comment: But it would still be interrupted after 90 minutes... Can you renew the login before the 90 minutes are up?

Comment: Do you know how this 90 minutes period is being count? Is this the period since the last action made on the website, or the time since the login?

Comment: It is the time since the first login. If you log in again before the time is up, it doesn't count. It is a university wireless authorization that was re-purposed for the dorms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a web page with some javascript behind it with a timer and every 90 minutes or so have it programmatically log yourself in using javascript DOM methods.

If the login is done by using a cookie you could always modify the cookie to never expire.